# How to open a file in different applications simultaneously?

Tags: c++, file-handling

Suppose I have two C++ applications name "App1" & "App2". Now in the App1, I am writing data to a file named "data.txt" and in the App2, I am reading the same file "data.txt" for its content.

Now what I have to do is to run the both applications simultaneously. How can I open the file "data.txt" at both locations simultaneously to do their operations?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a classic XY-problem. What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Is the file just there for these programs to communicate with eachother? In that case it seems like a [pipe](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inter_process_communication/inter_process_communication_pipes.htm) (or maybe a socket) would be more appropirate.

If there is more going on, it might be better to [lock the file](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?135061-Waiting-for-file-to-unlock) and let one program wait for the other to be done with its task on that file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to access a file by multi processes or threads. You can consider about file lock or communicating between two processes.

Comment: The case is i can't apply file lock as in the writing application i am reading data from the COM port of mobile and writing that data to file. Can't stop the reading data part.